# How is the Markov Property applied in this definition for Markov chain?

Tags: definition, markov-chains

I dont understand the infinitisemal definition from Wikipedia where it says

Let $X(t)$ be the random variable describing the state of the process at time t, and assume the process is in a state i at time t. By definition of the continuous-time Markov chain, $X(t+h)=j$ is independent of values prior to instant $t$; that is, it is independent of $X(s,s<t)$. With that in mind, for all $i,j$, for all $t$ and for small values of $h$, the following holds:

$\Pr(X(t+h)=j|X(t)=i)=\delta _{ij}+q_{ij}h+o(h)$
where $\delta _{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta and the little-o notation has been employed.

How does one arrive to this conclusion?

I know at time $t$ it is in $i$ and at time $t+h$ the chain must be in $j$. So the state holding time has to be less then $h$, the equation now assumes that after the holding time is finished it goes to $j$ and stays there until instant $t+h$. So $(1-e^{-\nu_ih})P_{ij} = (\nu_ih+o(h))P_{ij}$ if divided by $h$ the expression converges to $q_{ij}$ but why is it sufficient to calculate this value? Why do you not have to consider the event that the chain leaves i in less then $h$ timeunit and then goes to a series of different states within timeframe $h$ such that the last state before reaching the end of timeframe $h$ is $j$ ?

Comment: By your argument for one jump, you should see that the probability of having two or more jumps is $O(h^2)$, so that it is negligible in the limit.

Comment: Okay I understand a little but but I have still one problem. Is $\sum_{\mathbb{R}}o(h^2)/h= 0$ ? @max

Comment: "... why do we know it is an expression that goes to 0 if divided by ℎ?"  As you say, this is the definition of a continuous time Markov chain: it goes to zero by definition.  I don't understand what you are actually asking.

Comment: @New2Math I'm not sure what the expression $\Sigma_{\mathbb{R}} o(h^2)/h$ means. Answering your new question. The point is that the chance of two or more transitions occuring is $O(h^2)$ which is $o(h)$. In addition, you've already shown the the probability of transitioning directly from $i$ to $j$ is $\delta_{ij}+q_{ij}h+o(h)$. Combined, these show what you want.

Comment: @max I try to understand how one could calculate the probability of the event $A$ two or more transitions. There is one problem, there is an uncountable infinite ammount of events which constitutes the event $A$ ex. : $P(T_i<t_1)P(T_k<t_2)P_{ik}P_{kj}$ such that $t_1+t_2<h$, which is an expression = $O(h^2)$ however $t_1$ and $t_2$ are real. So to calculate $A$ you would look at $\mathbb{R}$ events which you would have to sum up, or have I missunterstood how to calculate chance of two ore more transitions?

Comment: * I meant $\lim_h\rightarrow 0\sum_{\mathbb{R}}o(h^2)/h= 0$

Comment: @max I think I understood I have two sum state holding timr take the convolution and then the sum gets discrete again and partialsums divided by h converge to 0

Comment: @New2Math I think you might benefit from reading a standard reference, such as chapter 5 of Ross http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~alex2014/SPpdf/Stochastic%20Processes%20SM.pdf as the wikipedia page is very sparse on a litany of technical details.

Comment: If you have some time could you please tell me how you calculated the term $O(h^2)$ ? I appreciate the source file you gave me. I plan to study stochastic processes once I have more time at hand @max

Comment: @New2Math You showed that one jump is $O(h)$, so two jumps is $O(h^2)$ (assuming all states are non-instantenous as wikipedia does). For one to occur between two points you need both holding times to be $O(h)$, which each of which ocurrs with $O(h)$ probability.